# Unzipp recursively even when the zip file has no folders

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a script which should unzipp a bunch of files. For some of these zip files, there isn't a structure made of folders. That means all the files are placed inside the archive o the same level and when I'm trying to unzipp them, all the files contained in the zip files are extracted at the same level. Thus all the files are mixed together and not placed individualy in the corresponding archive.

My idea is to create a new folder named from the corresponding zip Archive and do it for all the zip files included in the working directory.
However, I don't get it event if I'm using makedirs().

Here is my code :

```
os.chdir(directory)
cwd = os.getcwd()
print("Working directory :",cwd)

for ArchivesZip in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,'*.zip')):
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(ArchivesZip,'r')
    dir = os.path.join("extractions",ArchivesZip)
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.mkdir(ArchivesZip)
        zip_ref.extractall(dir)
```

Thanks for your advices...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create a folder named the same as the archive you're unpacking:

```
os.mkdir(ArchivesZip)
```

You probably wanted:

```
os.makedirs(dir)
```

Each .zip file should now get extracted to an 'extractions/path/to/archive.zip' folder inside your working dir.
If you want to change where the files are extracted, just modify the `dir` variable accordingly.
I'm not sure what exactly you want, but [os.path.basename()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) and [os.path.splitext()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) might be of use.

Also, note that `dir` shadows the `dir()` built-in, so it's a bad variable name.

Comment: Hi, I want to create folders named according to the archives that I would like to unzip. For exemple, if the archive file is named : johndoe.zip and the second one milenedoe.zip, I shoult get two folders. Respectively "johndoe" and "milenedoe" and inside each one, the contents extracted from the archives.

Comment: I've added some more info to the answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you Stranac.

This code works now!

Just something bothers me however. 
First, I need to use a global variable for the directory variable, reusable in the Extract Button. I'm not sure (as I begin to learn Python) that just declaring directory as a global variable is the good choice.

Any suggestion to improve the code are welcome :)

```
   # -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
from Tkinter import *
import zipfile,os,tkFileDialog,Tkinter,glob
#déclaration variables fenêtre Tkinter
master = Tk()
master.minsize(800,100)

#création fonction pour bouton d'appel
def callback():
#Ouverture navigateur, choix du dossier qui contient les zips
    global directory
    directory = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=master,initialdir="/Users/me/Downloads/",title='Please select a directory')
    if len(directory) > 0 :
        os.chdir(directory)
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        ExtractButton['state'] = 'active'


#ICI ça marche

def extraction():
#Ne cherche que les fichiers de type *.zip        
    for ArchivesZip in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,'*.zip')):    
        truncated_file = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(ArchivesZip))[0]
        print(truncated_file)
        if not os.path.exists(truncated_file):
            os.makedirs(truncated_file)
            zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(ArchivesZip,'r')
            zip_ref.extractall(truncated_file)
    ExtractButton['state'] = 'disabled'


#Appel des fonctions pour chacun des boutons. Parcourir et Extraire
SelectButton = Button(master, text="Parcourir", command=callback)
ExtractButton = Button(master, text="Extraction", state=DISABLED, command=extraction)

SelectButton.pack()
ExtractButton.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't know much about Tkinter, but it looks like you might want to read up on classes and oop.